# Upload blob block error with blockid > 1 char

Tags: .net, vb.net, azure

I'm uploading a file to an Azure blob using VB.NET and the Azure .NET assemblies.  As the file is large, I'm breaking it into blocks, and uploading with `CloudBlockBlob.PutBlock`.  The problem I'm having is if I supply a `BlockID` which is longer than one character, I'm getting a "The specified blob or block content is invalid." error from `PutBLock`.  If the blockID is only one charactor, it uploads fine.

```
Dim iBlockSize As Integer = 1024  ' KB
Dim alBlockIDs As New ArrayList
Dim iBlockID As Integer = 10

' Create the blob client.
Dim blobClient As CloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
' Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
Dim container As CloudBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer")
' Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
Dim blockBlob As CloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob")

Dim buffer(iBufferSize) As Byte
fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
Using ms As New MemoryStream(buffer)
    ' convert block id to Base64 Encoded string 
    Dim b64BlockID As String = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iBlockID.ToString(Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
    ' write the blob block
    blockBlob.PutBlock(b64BlockID, ms, Nothing)

    alBlockIDs.Add(b64BlockID)
    iBlockID += 1
End Using
```

If `iBlockID = 1`, the `PutBlock` method works fine (I still need to address the blockID being the same length for each block, I'll worry about that later).  Any ideas what's going on?  I'm currently testing with the local Azure storage emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant confirm but there might be chances in your code that you migh be overlapping some memory whlie creating those buffers. Please refer following working code to upload a Blob in blocks. Following code uses block size of **10240 (10KB)** but it can be changed easily

```
Dim fileName As String = "D:\Untitled.png"
Dim fileSize As Long = New FileInfo(fileName).Length
Dim blockNumber As UInteger = 0
Dim blocksize As UInteger = 10240 '10KB
Dim blockIdList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

Using fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    Do While (fileSize > 0)
        Dim bufferSize As UInteger

        'Last block of file can be less than 10240 bytes
        If (fileSize > blocksize) Then
            bufferSize = blocksize
        Else
            bufferSize = fileSize
        End If

        Dim buffer(bufferSize) As Byte
        Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)

        'move the file system reader to the proper position
        fs.Seek(blocksize * blockNumber, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        br.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)

        Using ms As New MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
            'convert block id to Base64 Encoded string 
            Dim b64BlockID As String = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("BlockId{0}", blockNumber.ToString("0000000"))))
            blockBlob.PutBlock(b64BlockID, ms, Nothing)

            blockIdList.Add(b64BlockID)
        End Using

        blockNumber += 1
        fileSize -= blocksize
    Loop

    blockBlob.PutBlockList(blockIdList)

End Using
```

Comment: When I used that code in my project, it threw the same exception.  I created a new project and used that code and it works fine.  I'll do some more investigation about what else in my original project might have been causing the problem (there was very little in my original project, so it's a bit weird).  Thanks Ojas, I appreciate the response.

Comment: This sample works fine, once I put it in a new project.  Thanks again.